# Bayesian Network alarm domain

Tags: java, graph, probability, bayesian-networks

I am having a bit of trouble with something that I imagine is fairly easy.
[image]

I am wondering how to get the probability of alarm, JohnCalls, and MaryCalls if they have no prior knowledge of their parents.

I assumed P(A) = P(A|B,E)*P(A|B,!E)...=.95*.94*.29*.001 = .00026

However, I can't make sense of this, as that is even lower than if there were no Burglary or Earthquake at all.  Likewise with JohnCalls, if JohnCalls even when there is no alarm 5% of the time, .90*.05 < 5% and that makes no sense to me.

I assume there is an easy solution to this, so thank you for your patience.

Also, I am trying to create this in a java program, and am having a bit of difficulty.  Can anyone recommend a good tutorial for a problem like this that will help me create a program in which I could query anything to do with a graph like this? Thanks again!

Comment: You should start with asking on http://math.stackexchange.com/ Your issue is mostly mathematical. For example, your assumption may be incorrect and the whole mess might have a simple answer. Once you know how the math works the Java code should be a piece of cake, but also a separate question if you run into trouble.

Comment: Great thanks! I was think bayesian networks were only related to AI and programming. Thank you for your insight. I will try that.